Как использовать .pfx файл
Есть определенный сайт (https://faktura.soliq.uz/faktura/uz/login/index), вход на который выполняется при помощи ЭЦП формата .pfx (используется модуль e-imzo). Как автоматически залогиниться на данном сайте? (python, beautiful soup)
